# SwiftUI: Observe internal changes in published object

Tags: swiftui

SwiftUI, Swift 5.2, Xcode 11.4

I'm trying to observe changes in a singleton, but I'm not always getting my SwiftUI view refreshed:

```
final class Patient: ObservableObject {
      static var shared: Patient
      @Published var medicalData: MedicalData

      init { ... }

      final class MedicalData { 
            var allergies: String
            var ...

            init { ... }
      }
}
```

So, in my SwiftUI view:

```
struct ContentView: View {
       @ObservedObject var patient: Patient = Patient.shared
       var body: some view { ... }
}
```

If any object replaces the medical data, the publisher will inform my SwiftUI correctly:

```
patient.medicalData = NEW_MEDICAL_DATA --> OK! View refreshed
```

But if any object changes a value IN current medical data, the SwiftUI View is not refreshed:

```
patient.medicalData.allergies = "Alcanfor" --> NOT PUBLISHED
```

Does anyone knows how to accomplish this?
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Found a elegant way to perform this (see `didSet`):

```
final class Patient: ObservableObject {
      static var shared: Patient
      @Published var medicalData = MedicalData() { 
           didSet {
                  subscription = medicalData.objectWillChange.sink { [weak self] _ in
                        self?.objectWillChange.send()
                  }
           }
      }
      var subscription: AnyCancellable?

      init { ... }
}
```

This works out of the box if the property was initialized. If not, just write also the `didSet` code after initialize the `medicalData` propertie at 'init()`.

Of course, `MedicalData` must conform the `ObservableObject` protocol.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest is to make it value type

```
  struct MedicalData { 
        var allergies: String
        var ...
```

This gives

```
  patient.medicalData.allergies = "Alcanfor" --> PUBLISHED
```

**Update:** Possible approach for CoreData object... I would still prefer to use struct, now as wrapper. It requires a bit additional efforts but allows to control what should affect view refresh and should not, and refresh itself works automatically via existed publish

```
// helper struct wrapper
struct CoreDataWrapper<T:NSManagedObject> {
    let value: T

    init(_ wrapped: T) {
        value = wrapped
    }

    private var refreshed = false
    private mutating func refresh() {
        refreshed.toggle()
    }
}

// helper protocol of properties visible to extensions (optionals - works w/o it as well)
protocol MedicalDataProtocol {
    var allergies: String? { get set }
}

// extension to wrapper for a specific class properties
extension CoreDataWrapper: MedicalDataProtocol where T == MedicalData {
    var name: String? {
        get { value.allergies }
        set { value.allergies = newValue; refresh() }
    }
}


// usage in view model

final class Patient: ObservableObject {
      static var shared: Patient
      @Published var medicalData: CoreDataWrapper<MedicalData>

      // ... other code here
```

Comment: Yeah, but it must be passed by reference because it is a CoreData object :/

Comment: @knshi, such important restriction should be posted in advance, see updated.